# Get JSON information in PHP

Tags: php, json

Im trying to get information in a JSON file as an array in my PHP so I can put it in my database. In this simple example my code works:

```
{
"tiles":[179, 199, 198, 198, 160, 198, 180, 199, 178, 160, 180, 180, 198, 160]
}

$string = file_get_contents(FileDestination);
$worldarray = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($worldarray['tiles'] as $item) {
    mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO blabla (test) VALUES('.$item.')');
}
```

However, it so happens that my JSON file is a bit more complicated:

```
{ "height":32,
"layers":[
    {
     "data":[179, 199, 198, 198, 160, 198, 180, 199, 178, 160, 180, 180, 198, 160, 178,],
     "height":32,
     "name":"Tile Layer 1",
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"tilelayer",
     "visible":true,
     "width":32,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    },
```

And so on. I need the information in Layers > Data. I've tried accessing it in all kinds of ways like using: $worldarray['layers']['data'] but I just dont seem to be able to get the the values from data. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It only looks more complicated, but it isn't. Just nested. `foreach ($worldarray['layers'][0]['data'] as $item)`

Comment: first of all; what is the output of `print_r(json_decode($string, true));`? (ot: nice nick, jan lul ;))

Comment: pls show the json data as it is in the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `layers` is a array, you should provide an index when you access, like:

```
$worldarray['layers'][0]['data']
```

In case you have more layers of course, you should iterate over them.

Comment: When I do this nothing is added to my database. This is the only layers and only data.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out my PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/673-dmb

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj->access_token;
```

try this way .i hope it's may be help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, it suddenly works now by using $array['layers'][0]['data']. Even though that didnt work for several times before.